# What are the steps for modifying (re-sculpting) the face and body of a purchased character (textured, rigged and posed)?

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode

I purchased a character I thought was close to what I needed thinking I could make minor changes to the face and body. I started by hiding the rig and separating the head and applying scale.[image: severed the head]

Then I switched to edit mode and selected a vertex in the center for the face and hit num-pad period so I could symetrize.
[image: edit mode, rotated head, set origin?]
Then I went into sculpt mode and made changes, went back to edit mode and just moved the face around a bit and went back to sculpt mode and this happened:
[image: switched to edit mode, rotated head, switched back to sculpt mode, and...]

I think it's because I started with a pose that wasn't a T pose and I didn't un-parent the rig but I'm guessing because I'm new to 3d (just 1 month). I know I will have to retopo the face and change the UV map and adjust the face rig and all the shapekeys.

I searched for a tutorial that gives an overview of the steps for doing this and can't find anything. I would appreciate any advice. I imagine I'm not the only one who wants to modify an existing character. BTW this is for an animation not a game engine. Meanwhile I'll try un-parenting the rig..